# How to get a field, where another field has is max value

Tags: sql-server, sql

Lets I have the following table

```
Key |ID  | Value
1   |2   | 3
2   |2   | 5
3   |3   | 1
```

I need a Query to get the ID and Value, where value is maximum, can I do this in a single query?

something like `SELECT ID, MAX(Value) FROM table`

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
   Key, ID, Value
FROM
   MyTable
ORDER BY
   Value DESC
```